# Python - Remove "tagged" item from list only if another item with greater "tag" exists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

My starting list (with "tagged" items as `[Ann]` and `nn` being a 2-digit integer) :

```
myList ['[A01]apple', '[A02]apple_sauce', '[A03]apple_juice', '[A04]banana', '[A05]banana_bread', '[A06]banana_ice']
```

My target list :

```
myTgtList  ['[A02]apple_sauce', '[A03]apple_juice', '[A05]banana_bread', '[A06]banana_icecream']
```

My goal :

- remove `[Ann]text` only if `[A(nn + 2)]text` exists in myList

My tries :

```
>>> for val in myList:
...     if ('[A' + str((int(val[2:4]) + 2)) + ']') in val:
...         print val
... 
>>> for val in myList:
...     if ('[A' + str((int(val[2:4]) + 2)) + ']') in myList:
...         print val
...     
>>> for val in myList:
...     if ('[A' + str((int(val[2:4]) + 2)) + ']') in enumerate(myList):
...         print val
...     
>>> newList = [s for s in myList if ('[A' + str((int(val[2:4]) + 2)) + ']') in myList]
>>> newList
[]
>>> newList = [s for s in myList if ('[A' + str((int(val[2:4]) + 2)) + ']')]
>>> newList
[]
```

I realize it may be similar to removing a duplicate, but I can't match the condition in any of my tries.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: your requirements don't match your target output.  `A05` and `A06` are the only things that should survive because `A(nn+2)` is in the `myList` for everything except those two.

Comment: Please update your filtering criteria - as Ryan states above, the one you've stated in the Q doesn't match the output.

Comment: btw, to meet your "goal" as stated `[item for item in myList if all(('A' + str(int(re.match(r'^\[A(\d+)\].*', item ).group(1)) + 2)) not in s for s in myList)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, is in this section of your code:

```
str((int(val[2:4]) + 2))
```

Observe:

```
>>> x="A02"
>>> x[1:3]
'02'
>>> int(x[1:3])
2
>>> str(int(x[1:3]))
'2'
>>> 'A'+str(int(x[1:3]))
'A2'
```

This meant that your code could never match as `A2` isn't in any of the tags, only `A02`.

[You can use any number of ways to correctly pad the string with zeros to the required widths.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

For example:

```
>>> 'A%02d'%(int(x[1:3]))
'A02'
>>> 'A{0:02d}'.format(int(x[1:3]))
'A02'
```

Here is a working example:

```
>>> l = ['[A01]apple', '[A02]apple_sauce', '[A03]apple_juice', '[B01]banana', '[A02]banana_bread', '[A03]banana_ice']
>>> [s for s in l if 'A%02d'%(int(s[2:4]) + 2) not in [t[1:4] for t in l]]
['[A02]apple_sauce', '[A03]apple_juice', '[A02]banana_bread', '[A03]banana_ice']
```

Normally I'd use `String.format` over the percent syntax, but the list comprehension was already getting quite long.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, I realized the examples I put in the question were wrong and that I'd need `myTgtList  ['[A02]apple_sauce', '[A03]apple_juice', '[A05]banana_bread', '[A06]banana_icecream']` (sorry :-( )

Comment: @iceman94 Well I've explained why your code wasn't working, and once you figure out what your filtering algorithm is, then the above should help ensure you can implement that.